# How to calculate approximate changes in a nonlinear function with non-independent variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, approximation

Given the expression
$$y_t = \frac{a_t +b_t}{b_t}= 1 +\frac{a_t}{b_t}$$
the change of $y_t$ for the time $t = [0,1]$ may be written

$$\Delta t=y_1-y_0=\biggl(1+\frac{a_1}{b_1}\biggr)-\biggl(1+\frac{a_0}{b_0}\biggr)
$$

It is now of interest to investigate how much the respective change in $\Delta a = a_1-a_0$ and
$\Delta b = b_1-b_0$ has affected the total change $\Delta y$.

A friend of mine formulated a solution which can be found in the PDF in the link below:

[Link to solution in PDF](https://www.scribd.com/document/352981270/Total-Derivatives)

My question to you guys in regards to the solution is

1. Is the solution correct?

   - If yes, is the solution applicable if either $\Delta a$ or/and $\Delta b$ is negative?
   - If no, any other way to approach this issue?

Comment: Is the algebraic notation in line $1$ correct? I think you mean $$\frac{a_t+b_t}{b_t} = 1+\frac{a_t}{b_t}$$

Comment: @Bacon you are right, wrong placement - now corrected

Comment: All seems ok to me in regards to the OP, the link also seems fine to me.